# (ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10)

Tags: python, literals

```
total = {}
count = 0
while(count < 4):
    _input = input()
    count = count + 1
    total[_input] = 0
    for i in range(5):
        _input2 = int(input())
        total[_input] = total[_input] + _input2      
print(total)
```

```
Virat,101,88,93,0,120
Rohit,50,100,30,140,80
Sky,10,20,30,40,50
Shreyas,100,0,0,100,0
```

Expected output:

> {'Virat': 402, 'Rohit': 400, 'Sky': 150, 'Shreyas': 200}

The code works perfectly fine on my system, but it shows error

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10

where I am solving questions

Comment: In the expression `int(input())`, the script will take input from the keyboard, and then try to turn it into an `int`.  What should happen if the user just hits enter instead of typing in a number?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please use complete sentences to explain **how** you try to use the program, **step by step**, and what you see as you do so. **Copy and paste** what you see in the terminal, and format it the same way as the code. Show a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message by **copying and pasting**, starting from the line that reads `Traceback (most recent call last):` until the end, and format that the same way as the code, too. Finally, please do not talk about yourself in questions, as this is **not a discussion forum**.

Comment: **Never** assume that interactive input can be converted to anything other than a string (str). Your issue is clearly here *int(input())*. Also, that's not the full exception message

Answer (score 1):

I checked your code running fine if you give input one by one. Like,

```
Virat
101
88
93
0
120
Rohit
50
..
```

If you want to give input like `Virat,101,88,93,0,120`, It stores value like `{'Virat,10,20,30,40,50': 0}`
And second input is '' and when it does `int('')` it will throw: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`

But if you want to give input like `Virat,101,88,93,0,120`, below is modified code:

```
total = {}
count = 0
while(count < 4):
    _input = input()
    count = count + 1
    name = _input.split(',')[0]
    runs = _input.split(',')[1:]
    total[name] = 0
    for run in runs:
        total[name] = total[name] + int(run)
print(total)
```

Where you can give input same as you displayed:

```
Virat,101,88,93,0,120
Rohit,50,100,30,140,80
Sky,10,20,30,40,50
Shreyas,100,0,0,100,0
```

And get output like: `{'Virat': 402, 'Rohit': 400, 'Sky': 150, 'Shreyas': 200}`